# Have the public static fields in android.os.Environment been removed? (Android 2.1)

Tags: android

Looking at the example code in the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29

```
File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

It does not compile on 2.1
The static fields DIRECTORY_PICTURES, DIRECTORY_MUSIC etc. don't seem to be found.

Update: 
Using the filter api checkbox, I see that it was removed in Android 2.2 (or api version 8). So the manifest file needs to contain minSdk defined as 7.

Comment: ad update: why do you think so? It's marked "Since: API Level 8"

Comment: Yes, I see it now. But I also see that getExternalFilesDir() is only from level 8. What should one use from level 3-7 (android 1.5 - 2.1) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this was added in Android 2.2 (API Level 8). See "Filter by API Level" in top right corner.

Comment: But I also see that getExternalFilesDir() is only from level 8. What should one use from level 3-7 (android 1.5 - 2.1) instead?

Comment: Try what returns these methods on 2.2 and hardcode it in your application.

Comment: will the directory name be constant? I am not so sure. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory%28%29" Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace. Any files that are private to the application should be placed in a directory returned by Context.getExternalFilesDir, which the system will take care of deleting if the application is uninstalled. "